# Jquery Ajax on site with bad SSL certificate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ssl

I'm having problems performing AJAX calls on my testbed system.

It doesn't have a valid SSL certificate for the domain instead using the one the production system uses as it's set up identically.

I'm guessing that it's because of the bad SSL certificate that my ajax requests are being forced to use HTTP instead of HTTPS.

I can confirm that the JS is loaded via HTTPS in the first place.

With the following Ajax call:

```
function ajaxPortfolioCall() { // catch the form's submit event
    var edit_portfolio_form = $('#editportfolioform');
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: edit_portfolio_form.serialize(), // get the form data
        type: edit_portfolio_form.attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: edit_portfolio_form.attr('action'), // the file to call
        success: function (response) { // on success..
            $('#editportfolioform').html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    });
}
```

Where the URL resolves to:

```
$(form_id).attr('action')
"/rate-tracker/portfolio/add/"
```

It is attempting to make a URL call via HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue of [mixed content blocking](https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/) which modern browsers have started warning about. The link gives plenty of information on how to resolve the issue, but the summary is that if mixed content (both HTTP and HTTPS) is found a shield icon will appear in the browser navbar somewhere. In Firefox it's on the left, on Chrome it's on the right. Clicking this will allow you to turn off the blocking for that domain IIRC.

Comment: All of the page is loaded via HTTPS, Nginx is set to redirect any HTTP url to HTTPS via a 301 status code